# Let $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}| x < a_n \hspace{2mm}\text{for infinitely many $a_n$}\}$. Find a subsequence converging to $\sup S$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a bounded sequence. Let $S = \{x \in \mathbb{R}| x < a_n \hspace{2mm}\text{for infinitely many $a_n$}\}$. Prove there exists a subsequence converging to supremum of $S$.

The part about "infinitely many terms" is confusing me a bit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to the site! The "infinitely many terms" means that if $x\in S$ then there exists infinitely many different $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x<a_{k}$.

Comment: How would I use this fact to construct a subsequence?

Comment: Do you have Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem? In that case can you find a $a_{n_{k}} \in [\sup S-\frac{1}{k}, \sup S]$ for every $k\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: "The part about "infinitely many terms" is confusing me a bit"  Consider $A\subset \{a_n\}$ is an infinite subset.  Then if $x < \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in A$ then $x \in S$.  $S = \{x\in \mathbb R|$ so that for *any* infinite subset of $\{a_n\}$, then $x$ is less than all the values in the subset$\}$....  Now the way I see it, you can easily show $\sup S = \sup \{a_n\}$.  Do you see how?

Comment: But then what will the convergent subsequence be? Or how does this imply that a subsequence exists?

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$
\xi_N:=\sup_{k\ge N}a_n
$$
So $\{\xi_N\}_{N\in\Bbb N}$ is a decreasing sequence, thus it admits limit $L$, which is finite, since $\{a_n\}_n$ is bounded by hypothesis.

Prove by yourself that $\{\xi_N\}_{N\in\Bbb N}$ is (one of the possible) sequence you are searching for, and $L=\sup S$.

Usually one refers to such a limit as $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$.

Comment: Why is this an increasing sequence?

Comment: $\xi_{N+1}$ is the $\inf$ on a strictly smaller subset than $\xi_{N}$

Comment: Consider the alternating sequence $a_n = (-1)^n$. Then the limit of your epsilon sequence would be -1. But this is clearly not the limit superior of $a_n$ which is 1. Did you mean to write sup in your definition of the sequence epsilon?

Comment: I may be wrong somewhere above

Comment: @MattAdamBarnes: you're right, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $\alpha = \sup S$. There are either (i) infinitely many $a_n$ with $a_n\geq \alpha$ or (ii) infinitely many $a_n$ with $a_n<\alpha$ (both could be true).

Suppose (i) is true. Then for all $k$, we find that $\alpha+\frac1k\not\in S$ so there are only finitely many $a_n$ with $a_n>\alpha+\frac1k$. Considering (i), this means there are infinitely many $a_n$ satisfying $\alpha\leq a_n\leq \alpha+\frac1k$. Construct a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ with $a_{n_k}\to \alpha.$

If (ii) is true, a similar approach is applied to $\alpha-\frac1k$. Since $\alpha-\frac1k\in S$, there are infinitely many $a_n$ with $a_n>\alpha-\frac1k$. If $(\alpha-\frac1k,\alpha)$ contains an infinite number of $a_n$ terms, then the argument is similar to case (i). Otherwise, it must be true that an infinite number of $a_n$ satisfy $a_n\geq \alpha$, in which case we are in case (i).